# Reordering numpy array indices

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have a 2D array that I want to create an image from. I want to transform the `image` array of dimensions 140x120 to an array of 140x120x3 by stacking the same array 3 times (to get a grayscale image to use with skimage).

I tried the following:

```
image = np.uint8([image, image, image])
```

which results in a 3x120x140 image. How can I reorder the array to get 120x140x3 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.dstack([image, image, image])` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)) will return an array of the desired shape, but whether this has the right semantics for your application depends on your image generation library.

Comment: I was using skimage, so it worked. I'll add that detail to the question.